# Best NLP Library for German language in Python?

Tags: library, python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Hello I am facing a project where I have to analyze lots of text data. Its data is not a typical text - it is all business plans.

Are there any useful libraries for Python I could use to evaluate the text/words of sentimental, grammartense, POS, and so on?

Maybe you have had a similar project and could recommend a library which is accurate to me!

Thanks in advance! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

this [Holmes Project](https://spacy.io/universe/project/holmes) would be very useful in your case, Build on SpaCy, this is specifically for English and German language, I haven't tried it yet, but looks promising, you can get to know everything in the Readme. Here is the [Demo](https://holmes-demo.xt.msg.team/) . you can also find Github repo where extensive readme is available.

I can suggest you the following, which are well maintained and have all features you required.POS, semantic, dependecy, stemming, stopwords, etc

1. [CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html)
2. [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage)
3. [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

and to achieve your desired results, from my experience you mostly required to use combination of libraries or tools, like I used once NLTK, SenticNet, CoreNLP together. You probably wont find everything in one.